# remove default WEB-INF/views/

Tags: spring-roo

How can I remove default jspx Spring Roo WEB-INF/views/. I have my own controllers. 
If I just deploy the war file and and remove the WEB-INF/views/ the application fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may be failing because the spring config (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml`) is referring to the view folder:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
      <list>
        <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</value>
        <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

If you aren't using tiles you could try removing the above definitions.